# How to make the two textview more flexible in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been searching around but didnt fine any clues about how to make the 2 textview flexible according to the space. Here is the picture. Any hint, it would great. [image: Edited]

Comment: Unclear. What "flexible" should mean? Using `wrap_content` seems enough "flexible", to me.

Comment: I edited my question. I want it look exactly like the one in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/incoming_message_bg"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:maxWidth="250dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Note : **incoming_message_bg** must be **[Nine patch image](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)** . And you can mutiple textview in Linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It is working fine.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text1"
            android:textSize="17sp" 
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"/>


      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is some text"
            android:textSize="17sp" 
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"/>

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank for your help, but it seem it didnt work for me.